# possible index by column number (not label) without iloc?

Tags: python, pandas

Can we index both the row and column in pandas **without** using`.iloc`? The documentations says

> With DataFrame, slicing inside of [] slices the rows.

But when I want to include both row and column in the same fashion, it is not working.

```
   data = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns = list('abcde'))
   data[0:2] #only rows
   data.iloc[0:2,0:3] # works.
   data[0:2,0:3] # not working in python, but it works similarly in R
```

Comment: What is wrong with using `.iloc[]`?

Comment: I learnt R first and am not quite used to the python. Also, it takes a little more typing.

Comment: In Pandas you would want to use `.loc[rows, columns]` for label slicing or `.iloc[row#, col#]` for positional slicing. Docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges

Comment: The whole purpose of `.iloc` is to allow this.  Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @BrenBarn In R, you can do it using [ ] behind a dataframe without any extra function or attributes. I was just wondering whether iloc is the only way to index column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that using `iloc` is probably the clearest solution, but indexing by row and column number simultaneously can be done with two separate indexing operations. Unless you use `iloc`, I don't think pandas knows if you are looking for columns number 0-3, or columns named 0, 1, 2, and 3

```
data[0:2][data.columns[0:3]]
```

This is fairly clear though in showing exactly what you are selecting. Otherwise, you'll have to drop into array indexing to get your subset.

```
data.values[0:2,0:3]
```